# where can I find a *.vim file for the default color scheme

Tags: vim

After browsing tens of color schemes, I couldn't really find anything much better than the "default" vim color scheme.

I would like to twist it a little bit, but couldn't find the scheme file, does such file exist? or is there a way I can save current scheme into a file and edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be system dependent, but to see the name of the current colorscheme just use

```
:colorscheme
```

If it is `default`, you can find it via `locate default.vim` or `find / -name default.vim`.

For me it's in

```
/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/default.vim
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim
```

won't help you much as it doesn't define a single visual attribute for a single highlight group. The actual default colors are defined in two places.

Some highlight groups get their visual attributes defined with a "special" syntax in:

```
$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

Here is the gist of it (as of April 2023):

```
if &background == "dark"
  SynColor Comment  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Cyan ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#80a0ff guibg=NONE
  SynColor Constant term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=Magenta ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#ffa0a0 guibg=NONE
  SynColor Special  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightRed ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=Orange guibg=NONE
  SynColor Identifier   term=underline cterm=bold ctermfg=Cyan ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#40ffff guibg=NONE
  SynColor Statement    term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=NONE gui=bold guifg=#ffff60 guibg=NONE
  SynColor PreProc  term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightBlue ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#ff80ff guibg=NONE
  SynColor Type     term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightGreen ctermbg=NONE gui=bold guifg=#60ff60 guibg=NONE
  SynColor Underlined   term=underline cterm=underline ctermfg=LightBlue gui=underline guifg=#80a0ff
  SynColor Ignore   term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=bg guibg=NONE
else
  SynColor Comment  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkBlue ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=Blue guibg=NONE
  SynColor Constant term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkRed ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=Magenta guibg=NONE
  " #6a5acd is SlateBlue
  SynColor Special  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkMagenta ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#6a5acd guibg=NONE
  SynColor Identifier   term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkCyan ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=DarkCyan guibg=NONE
  SynColor Statement    term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Brown ctermbg=NONE gui=bold guifg=Brown guibg=NONE
  " #6a0dad is Purple
  SynColor PreProc  term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkMagenta ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#6a0dad guibg=NONE
  SynColor Type     term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGreen ctermbg=NONE gui=bold guifg=SeaGreen guibg=NONE
  SynColor Underlined   term=underline cterm=underline ctermfg=DarkMagenta gui=underline guifg=SlateBlue
  SynColor Ignore   term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermfg=white ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=bg guibg=NONE
endif
SynColor Error      term=reverse cterm=NONE ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red gui=NONE guifg=White guibg=Red
SynColor Todo       term=standout cterm=NONE ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Yellow gui=NONE guifg=Blue guibg=Yellow
```

That block is followed by another one which links a number of common highlight groups to the ones listed above:

```
SynLink String      Constant
SynLink Character   Constant
SynLink Number      Constant
SynLink Boolean     Constant
SynLink Float       Number
SynLink Function    Identifier
SynLink Conditional Statement
SynLink Repeat      Statement
SynLink Label       Statement
SynLink Operator    Statement
SynLink Keyword     Statement
SynLink Exception   Statement
SynLink Include     PreProc
SynLink Define      PreProc
SynLink Macro       PreProc
SynLink PreCondit   PreProc
SynLink StorageClass    Type
SynLink Structure   Type
SynLink Typedef     Type
SynLink Tag     Special
SynLink SpecialChar Special
SynLink Delimiter   Special
SynLink SpecialComment  Special
SynLink Debug       Special
```

One thing should be immediately obvious: those highlight groups are all related to **syntax** highlighting, the syntactic-relevant tokens in your text. The chrome of the editor, its UI, is not handled here.

The highlight groups used for the chrome of the editor (the status line, line numbers, visual selection, diff colors when in diff mode, etc.) are handled within Vim itself, in `src/highlight.c`. The whole thing is pretty long so here is a sample, as of April 2023:

```
static char *(highlight_init_both[]) = {
    CENT("ErrorMsg term=standout ctermbg=DarkRed ctermfg=White",
     "ErrorMsg term=standout ctermbg=DarkRed ctermfg=White guibg=Red guifg=White"),
    CENT("IncSearch term=reverse cterm=reverse",
     "IncSearch term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse"),
    CENT("ModeMsg term=bold cterm=bold",
     "ModeMsg term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold"),
    CENT("NonText term=bold ctermfg=Blue",
     "NonText term=bold ctermfg=Blue gui=bold guifg=Blue"),
    CENT("StatusLine term=reverse,bold cterm=reverse,bold",
     "StatusLine term=reverse,bold cterm=reverse,bold gui=reverse,bold"),
    CENT("StatusLineNC term=reverse cterm=reverse",
     "StatusLineNC term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse"),
    "default link EndOfBuffer NonText",
    CENT("VertSplit term=reverse cterm=reverse",
     "VertSplit term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse"),
#ifdef FEAT_CLIPBOARD
    CENT("VisualNOS term=underline,bold cterm=underline,bold",
     "VisualNOS term=underline,bold cterm=underline,bold gui=underline,bold"),
#endif
#ifdef FEAT_DIFF
    CENT("DiffText term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=Red",
     "DiffText term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=Red gui=bold guibg=Red"),
#endif
    CENT("PmenuSbar ctermbg=Grey",
     "PmenuSbar ctermbg=Grey guibg=Grey"),
    CENT("TabLineSel term=bold cterm=bold",
     "TabLineSel term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold"),
    CENT("TabLineFill term=reverse cterm=reverse",
     "TabLineFill term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse"),
#ifdef FEAT_GUI
    "Cursor guibg=fg guifg=bg",
    "lCursor guibg=fg guifg=bg", // should be different, but what?
#endif
    "default link QuickFixLine Search",
    "default link CursorLineSign SignColumn",
    "default link CursorLineFold FoldColumn",
    "default link CurSearch Search",
    "default link PmenuKind Pmenu",
    "default link PmenuKindSel PmenuSel",
    "default link PmenuExtra Pmenu",
    "default link PmenuExtraSel PmenuSel",
    CENT("Normal cterm=NONE", "Normal gui=NONE"),
    NULL
};
```

Basically, the *chrome* highlight groups, which are necessary for Vim to function correctly, are hardcoded so that Vim can use them in every scenario, and the *syntax* highlight groups, which are not as necessary, are distributed as part of the runtime.

Now, reconstructing an actual `default` standalone colorscheme out of those bits of information is not particularly difficult: you put all of those blocks of text in a file and you use your Vim-fu to edit the whole thing into shape. But it is not necessary.

In fact, since Vim reverts to `default` no matter what after a `hi clear`, it would be simpler to just put the few desired overrides in a skeleton colorscheme file:

```
" ~/.vim/colors/mydefault.vim
hi clear
let g:colors_name = 'mydefault'

if &background ==# 'dark'
    hi ...
else
    hi ...
endif
```

which doesn't require knowledge of what colors the default colorscheme actually uses.

And it would be even simpler to just override what needs to be overridden with [an autocommand](https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/wiki/How-to-override-a-colorscheme%3F) in one's `vimrc`.

Comment: What about colors for `vimdiff` **default colorscheme**? Those are not in the default colorscheme file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim`. For any other colorscheme, `vimdiff` colors (such as `DiffDelete` and so on) are defined in their  `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/xxx.vim` file, but not for the default one. See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10898/41943

Comment: OK @4wk_ I will add a bit of precision.

Comment: @4wk_ answer updated with a lot more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is in my default.vim file

```
" Vim color file
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last Change:  2001 Jul 23

" This is the default color scheme.  It doesn't define the Normal
" highlighting, it uses whatever the colors used to be.

" Set 'background' back to the default.  The value can't always be estimated
" and is then guessed.
hi clear Normal
set bg&

" Remove all existing highlighting and set the defaults.
hi clear

" Load the syntax highlighting defaults, if it's enabled.
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "default"

" vim: sw=2
```

As you can see there are no colors defined. However you can take a look at the other color schemes in the same folder as `default.vim` to get an idea of how to define colors, you can then either add them to the `default.vim` or create your own colorscheme.

Also see

```
:help coloring
```